# Segment length by using trigonometry: absolute value of trigonometric function?

Tags: trigonometry, analytic-geometry, education, numerical-calculus

I'd like to compute the length $L$ in figure. Is it correct to do it in the following way ($H=0.247$)?

$$ L = H \, \mid \sin(\gamma) \mid = 9.4 \,\, 10^{−4} $$

where $\gamma = \pi - \theta_1 - \theta_2 = \pi - \frac{\pi}{4} - 2.36 $.

If I use:

$$ L = H \, \sin(\gamma) = −9.4 \,\, 10^{−4} $$

it is negative, thus it should be wrong.

[image]

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is $\gamma$ supposed to be in the second quadrant? $\frac{\pi}{4}+2.36 > \pi$, so the angle ends up in the third quadrant. (Which means subtracting it from $\pi$ will give you the angle in the fourth quadrant. Either way, the sine of this angle becomes negative.) Hence, the side $L$ should be pointing downward. Are you sure $m\angle\theta_2 = 2.36$? It seems pretty close to $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, so did you round it?

Comment: Hello @KM101, I'm sure about the numerical values of the angles; the segment H in figure is your right forearm when you ride your bike.

Comment: ..I rounded it, the original value is $\theta_2 = 2.3561944901923$.

Comment: I guessed so, that's $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ to $13$ decimal places. But then, you get exactly $0$ for $\gamma$, which means you also get $0$ for $L$...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the correct approach.

If your answer is wrong, are you sure it isn't $2.36$ degrees, or perhaps was $2.36$ a result of rounding?

If you did, multiply degrees by $π/180$ to get the radian angle.

If your $\theta_i$ are correct, your answer is too.